# NSInternalInconsistencyException with legacy ObjC code in Xcode 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, legacy-code

I've just began learning swift and I can't seem to figure out how to fix the following legacy code from a music app my company launched in 2016. I working towards updating the platform, but the app crashes each time I select My Profile, so I assume it's somewhere in UITableViewCell, however, this is inferred due to the following:

> "Assertion failure in -[UITableView
>   _dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:usingPresentationValues:],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3698.33.7/UITableView.m:7883
>   2018-01-16 21:41:01.168538-0500 Gleamy[4101:1978203] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: 'Attempted to dequeue multiple cells for the same index path,
>   which is not allowed. If you really need to dequeue more cells than
>   the table view is requesting, use the 
>   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method (without an index path).
>   Cell identifier: cell, index path: 
>   {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'

*** First throw call stack:

> (0x181c3a364 0x180e80528 0x181c3a238 0x1825d57f4 0x18b51a44c
>   0x18b353570 0x100b53334 0x18b52bac4 0x18b52c028 0x18b50a8ac
>   0x18b2c133c 0x18b1edf00 0x185c7d998 0x185c81b20 0x185bee36c
>   0x185c15b90 0x185c169d0 0x181be1edc 0x181bdf894 0x181bdfe50
>   0x181affe58 0x1839acf84 0x18b25467c 0x100b7d2b8
>   0x18161c56c)libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of
>   type NSException"

Thread 1: signal SIGABRT:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
```

}

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


if (indexPath.row==0)
{
    HeaderCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"headercell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    objectForKey:@"profile_pic"]  , @"cover_pic":[response objectForKey:@"cover_pic"],  @"follow_count":[response objectForKey:@"follow_count"],  @"following_count":[response objectForKey:@"following_count"]   ,   @"user_name":[response objectForKey:@"user_name"], @"name":[response objectForKey:@"name"],};


    NSMutableDictionary *data= response;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(GalleryClicked)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [cell.img_gallery setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [cell.img_gallery addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];



    UITapGestureRecognizer *viewProfilepic = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(showProfilePic)];
    viewProfilepic.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [cell.img_profilepic setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [cell.img_profilepic addGestureRecognizer:viewProfilepic];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *viewcoverpic = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(showCoverPic)];
    viewcoverpic.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [cell.img_coverPic setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [cell.img_coverPic addGestureRecognizer:viewcoverpic];



    [cell.btn_message addTarget:self action:@selector(myMessages) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.btn_notification addTarget:self action:@selector(notifications) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell setUpHeaderCellWithData:data];


    if ([data objectForKey:@"profile_pic"])
    {
        if ([[data objectForKey:@"profile_pic"] containsString:@"http"])
            profilPicUrl=[data objectForKey:@"profile_pic"];
        else
            profilPicUrl=@"http://gleamedm.com/reb/img/fans/profile_pic/default.jpg";
    }


    if ([data objectForKey:@"cover_pic"])
    {
        if ([[data objectForKey:@"cover_pic"] containsString:@"http"])
            coverPicUrl=[data objectForKey:@"cover_pic"];

        else
            coverPicUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://gleamedm.com/reb/img/fans/cover_pic/%@",[data objectForKey:@"cover_pic"]];
    }
    else
        coverPicUrl=@"http://gleamedm.com/reb/img/fans/cover_pic/default.jpg";




    return cell;
}
else
{
    int index=(int)indexPath.row-1;    // bcoz 0 is for header
    indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];

    SinglePost *postObj = (SinglePost *)[posts objectAtIndex:index];

    if (postObj.msg_postImgStr .length >0)
    {
        MyProfileDataCell2 *cell=(MyProfileDataCell2*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"dataCell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        [cell setupCellWithPostObject:postObj];
        [cell.textView setDelegate: self];
        cell.textView.tag=index;


        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(Postclicked:)];
        [cell.topView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [cell.topView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture2];
        [cell.topView setTag:index];


        [cell.btn_comment addTarget:self action:@selector(commentClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.btn_likeUnlike addTarget:self action:@selector(likeUnlikeClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        cell.btn_likeUnlike.tag=cell.btn_comment.tag=index;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *viewcoverpic = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(PostPictureClicked:)];
        viewcoverpic.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [cell.img_messagePic setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [cell.img_messagePic addGestureRecognizer:viewcoverpic];
        [cell.img_messagePic setTag:index];


        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        DataCell1 *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        [cell setupCellWithPostObject:postObj];

        [cell.textView setDelegate: self];
        cell.textView.tag=index;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(Postclicked:)];
        [cell.topView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [cell.topView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture2];
        [cell.topView setTag:index];


        [cell.btn_comment addTarget:self action:@selector(commentClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.btn_likeUnlike addTarget:self action:@selector(likeUnlikeClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        cell.btn_likeUnlike.tag=cell.btn_comment.tag=index;
        return cell;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of these lines:

```
int index=(int)indexPath.row-1;    // bcoz 0 is for header
indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
```

when the cellForRowAt method is called with indexPath 0-1, the dequeue call in your code is using indexPath 0-0, for which a cell has already been dequeued (when cellForRowAt was called with indexPath 0-0).  Hence the error.  (I can only assume that this internal consistency check is new in a recent release of iOS, and was not present when the code was first written.)

The code doesn’t seem to use the indexPath except for the dequeue calls, so I think you can just delete the second line above: you should keep the first line, as it remaps your array index to the correct row, to allow for the header at row 0.

Comment: You're correct, this was the issue. Thanks for your insight!